# Validação de dados com mvc asp.net (edição)

Tags: asp.net, validação, asp.net-mvc-4

Eu tenho um cadastro de usuário onde eu uso o remote validation no data annotation  para verificar se o usuário que está sendo cadastrado já existe, o meu problema é na edição, como estou alterando e usando o mesmo objeto o sistema acha que estou cadastrando um novo usuário e informa que não posso cadastrar pois o registro informado já existe.

Como faço para que quando eu estiver editando o registro ele não verifique duplicidade?

Meu modelo

```
            [DisplayName("E-mail")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Favor informar o E-mail do usuário")]
            [Remote("Unico", "Usuario", ErrorMessage = "Esse e-mail já existe no sistema")]
            [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Favor informe um e-mail válido")]
            public string email{ get; set; }
```

E aqui eu tenho a função de validação remota

```
public ActionResult Unico(string email)
        {
            try
            {
                int idUsuario = 123;//Usuário/ADM de teste

                Models.user = bd.users.SingleOrDefault(s => s.email == email && s.idUsuario == idUsuario);
                bool retorno = false;
                if (c == null)
                {
                    retorno = true;
                }
                return Json(retorno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Você pode colocar trechos do seu código do `Controller` que faz essas operações mencionadas na pergunta?

Comment: Editei incluindo trechos do código

Comment: Duas coisas: o MVC tem uma tag chamada `[EmailAddress]`, que possivelmente valida até melhor o e-mail que a expressão regular usada. A segunda coisa é: onde está o código que salva o registro?

Comment: Tenho que confirmar mais acho que o MVC4 não tem a validação [EmailAdress], não a problemas com objetos e nem gravação de dados. a minha questão é que ao editar o usuário ele informa que esse e-mail já existe no banco pelo fato de utilizar o remote validation.

Answer (score 1):

Já tive esse problema, mas eu não usava o *remote validation*.

No meu caso, ocorreu quando ao receber o objeto o ID estava igual a zero. Assim, o framework de persistência que eu estava utilizando entendia que se tratava de um novo objeto a ser cadastrado.

Verifique se na sua Action o ID do usuário cadastrado está sendo recebido.

Caso não esteja, renderize esse ID na View (em um input hidden por exemplo) para que ele possa ser enviado no post para sua Action.

Caso não seja a essa situação, edite a pergunta adicionando o código do seu Controller para tentarmos ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

`RemoteAttribute` espera um `JsonResult`, e não um `ActionResult`. Qualquer coisa diferente de `true` ele interpreta como um erro. Pode ser um erro de interpretação.

```
public JsonResult Unico(string email)
{
    try
    {
        int idUsuario = 123;//Usuário/ADM de teste
        Models.user = bd.users.SingleOrDefault(s => s.email == email && s.idUsuario == idUsuario);
        if (c == null)
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "O e-mail {0} já existe no sistema", email), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json("Erro! " + e.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Com isso você pode simplificar seu `[Remote]`, com mais mensagens de erro até:

```
[Remote("Unico", "Usuario")]
```

Há mais exemplos aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx